# Facebook Marketing API Ads Insights

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights, facebook-marketing-api

I'm currently trying  to access, through my marketing app, all the insights of my ads/campaings/ads account (clicks,impressions,etc). The tokens I generate has permissions for `ads_management`,`ads_read`,`read_insights` and `manage_pages`.

Nevertheless, I always get this answer:

```
{"data":[],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"MAZDZD","after":"LTEZD"}}}
```

(I get that response after I post something like

```
curl -G \
-d "fields=impressions" \
-d "access_token=my_access_token" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_MyAccountNumber/insights"
```

And then make a get using the report id, when the report id is completed)

I added my account as admin of the app and also added it in the Authorized Ad Account IDs list.

My app has development level access.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you had impressions recently?
Because I observe similar thing when try to access it with default [`date_preset`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/) that is 30 days:

```
> get "act_*****/insights", "impressions"
=> []
> get "act_*****/insights?date_preset=lifetime", "impressions"
=> ["11"]
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem ;)