# facebook marketing insights empty response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying really hard to get insights for an ad account my business manager manages.

I have been digging through the documentation for past couple days and read many stack overflow questions to no result.

No matter what I try, I simply get

```
{
    "data" : []
}
```

These are some things I have tried:

`<facebook_url>/v2.10/act_<accountID>/insights?fields=account_id`
`<facebook_url>/v2.10/act_<accountID>/insights?fields=impressions&date_preset=lifetime`

They all respond with empty response.

Strangely enough, `<facebook_url>/v2.10/act_<accountID>?fields=name` gives me exactly what I want:

```
{
    "name": <account_name>,
    "id"  : <account_id>
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that ads ran in that account during this time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Marketing API Ads Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768948/facebook-marketing-api-ads-insights)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not run any ads and have 0 ad spend, insights endpoint will not return those nodes. Only nodes which have data in the given time range are sent via the insights endpoint.